# How to inject a mocked object inside mock of another mocked object in Java?

Tags: java, mockito

I have below classes. DataServices object is used in both ProductImpl and Mapper. But its mock is available in ProductImpl but not in Mapper class. I do not what needs to be done so that mocked of DataServices is Available in Mapper class too.

```
class ProductImpl{
    @Inject private DataServices ds;
    @Inject private Mapper mapper;

    public void call(){
      ds.get(); //ds is not null here
      mapper.map();
     // some code
    }
   }



abstact class Mapper{

        @Inject private DataServices ds;

        public void map(){
            ds.get()// ds is null here
            //some code
        }
    }
```

I have test class below

```
class Test{

    @Mock private DataServices ds;
    @Mock private Mapper mapper;
    @InjectMocks private ProductImpl impl;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
    }

    @Test
    public void test(){
       impl.call();
    }
}
```

Comment: A mocked object doesn't need any of its traditional dependencies. A mocked object that has a void method called will do nothing.

Comment: ds get () returns an object

Comment: From the shown code it does not look that way.

Comment: Your Mapper is mocked. Whatever actual implementation and dependencies its method have doesn't matter. A mock does what you tell it to do.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you don't need another mocking in Mapper because you already mock the mapper class also the map method is void although if a method has returned something you can easily use `when` to provide a behavior that you need in your test.